# Probability measure of a small interval

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, uniform-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\mu$ be a **non-atomic** probability measure defined on $\mathbb R$. Let $I$ simply be an interval of length $\beta$, i.e., $ I = [i \beta,(i+1)\beta]$ for some $i \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $B$ any Borel set. I have the following fact given to me, which I was not able to refute yet and might well be correct:

> $\mu(I \cap B) \rightarrow \mu(I) \dfrac{\mathrm{Len}(I \cap B)}{\mathrm{Len}(I)}$ as $\beta\downarrow 0$.

Here $\mathrm{Len}$ denotes the 1-D volume or the exterior measure.

This is a bit hard to imagine. The intuition (which may fail most of the times at measure theory) says that this is roughly dividing the probability assigned to interval $I$ by its length so that we have a 'unit/uniform' measure now. Then we assign this unit measure to the length of $I \cap B$ simply by multiplication. How can we prove this result, if this is true? If not, what are the minimum number of assumptions we need such that this is true?

Comment: How are you defining $Len(I \cap B)$?

Comment: @user6247850 I did not do that yet, I was hoping for the 1-D volume (exterior measure).

Comment: If $\mu$ is non-atomic then as $\beta \to 0$, $\mu(I \cap B) \to 0$. So in some sense you want to claim that this is the "leading order term" in the asymptotic expansion as $\beta \to 0$. (Or refute that, too.)

Comment: So it seems like perhaps you want $\sim$ in place of $\to$ in the statement.  I am also not quite sure of the role of $i$; is it fixed once and for all, or what?

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for your comment. $i$ is defined such that $I$ is an interval of length $\beta$. I  can change my wording there to be more specific.

Comment: Yeah, I still don't get it.  Both sides of your limit depend on both $i$ and $\beta$, so it is of the form $f(i, \beta) \to g(i, \beta)$ as $\beta \downarrow 0$.  I hope you understand why it doesn't make sense to have $\beta$ on the right side?  And is it supposed to hold for some $i$, or for all $i$, or for some $i$ a function of $\beta$, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your question as follows.

> Let $\mu$ be a non-atomic probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $B$ be a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then, $$\lim_{\beta \downarrow 0} \frac{\mu([0,\beta]\cap B)/\mu([0,\beta])}{|[0,\beta]\cap B|/|[0,\beta]|} = 1,$$ where $|\cdot|$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

This claim is definitely false. One can take $\mu = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}\text{Unif}([2^{-2^k-1},2^{-2^k}])$, where $\text{Unif}(I)$ denotes the uniform probability measure over $I$, and $B = \cup_{k=1}^\infty [2^{-2^k-2},2^{-2^k}]$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may not be correct for all cases. Consider a positive decreasing sequence $\beta_n \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$. We have that
$\textrm{Len}(I_n)=\beta_n$. Let's consider $I_n=[0,\beta_n]$ (i.e. $i=0$). We have that $I_1 \supset I_2 \supset I_3 \supset ...$ and $I_\infty=\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}I_n=\{0\}$. So $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(I_n)=\mu(\{0\})$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(I_n \cap B)=\mu(B \cap \{0\})$. Let $B$ be $(-\varepsilon,0]$ for some $\varepsilon >0$. We have that $\textrm{Len}(I_n \cap B)=\textrm{Len}(\{0\})=0,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. So
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\textrm{Len}(I_n \cap B)}{\textrm{Len}(I_n)}\mu(I_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}0 = 0$$
which is not necessarily equal to $\mu(B \cap \{0\})=\mu(\{0\})$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, isn't probability measure on a singleton always $0$?

Comment: A probability measure is a measure on a set $X$ such that $\mu(X)=1$, nothing else

Comment: That is a good point, thank you. Which additional assumptions are needed so that the statement above is correct?

Comment: I think the measure should be non-atomic, am I right?

Comment: Yes, it could be a needed assumption

Comment: Added that, thanks so much!